# Sequence of dependent axios requests in react-query mutate functions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-query

I have a usecase to allow a user to edit data, stored in two database tables, from one Formik form.  All the below is therefore triggered via one press of a form submit button.

My edit functions consist of two react-query mutate functions, which each call two axios requests.  The first axios request deletes certain rows from my database, then the next request adds new rows to the database, as follows:

```
    //React-Query function to post data to member_events table
    const useMemberEventsEditMutationME = () => {
      return useMutation((formPayload) => {
        //Below variables extract data from first object (i.e. object zero) in the array in formPayload
        const eventDate = formPayload[0].event_date;
        const eventID = formPayload[0].EventEventId;
        // deletes all event->date combinations first, then creates new rows
        return (
          axios.delete(
            process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL + '/memberevents/memberdelete', { 
              data: { event_date: eventDate, eventID: eventID } 
          }),
          axios.post(
            process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL + '/memberevents/mememberevents',
            formPayload
          )
        );
      });
    };
    
    //React-Query function to post data to staff_events table
    const useMemberEventsEditMutationSE = () => {
      return useMutation((formPayload) => {
        //Below variables extract data from first object (i.e. object zero) in the array in formPayload
        const eventDate = formPayload[0].event_date;
        const eventID = formPayload[0].event_id;
        // deletes all event->date combinations first, then creates new rows
        return (
          axios.delete(process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL + '/memberevents/staffdelete', {
            data: { event_date: eventDate, eventID: eventID }
          }),
          axios.post(
            process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL + '/memberevents/mestaffevents',
            formPayload
          )
        );
      });
    };
```

I need the axios requests in each function to run in sequence, and most of the time they do - firstly deleting existing data, then adding new data.

But sometimes they don't run in sequence, and I don't know why.  An easy way to recreate the issue is to repeatedly and fairly rapidly click the form's submit button, then the issue will occur every few times it is clicked (maybe every 4 or 5 times it is clicked).  Looking in the browser network tab I can see, as an example of the issue, the following sequences of axios requests (which also each return 200 success statuses).

So rather than running in the sequence:

```
/memberevents/memberdelete    DEL
/memberevents/mememberevent   POST
/memberevents/staffdelete     DEL
/memberevents/mestaffevents   POST
```

It is running in the sequence:

```
/memberevents/memberdelete    DEL
/memberevents/mestaffevents   POST
/memberevents/mememberevent   POST
/memberevents/staffdelete     DEL
```

This is one example of it not working as needed.  I have observed other issues with sequence, but they are harder to recreate - the above issue occurs regularly.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how it might be resolved?  If additional parts of my code are needed to advise, e.g. the routes code or the code that triggers the react-queries, please let me know and I can edit it.

Comment: Just make the mutation function `async` and execute each request in turn, prefixed with `await`

Comment: Thanks Phil, I'll check out that potential solution and confirm if it worked after some testing.
To anyone else: please can this not be closed as a duplicate until I run some tests and confirm.

Comment: Phil's suggestion worked, and I now understand async/await better too!  I'll add an answer in here showing exactly the change I made in case it helps others, as soon as S.O. allows me to add an answer (a day or two from now).

Comment: The better option is to accept the duplicate